# Writing cell array into a text file

Tags: cell, text-files, printf

I'm having hard time with writing a cell array into a text file. If anyone can assist me with this,it would be highly appreciated;

Lets say my cell array is C =

```
[1x5 double]    [0.1962]    [1x3 double]    [2x3 double]
>> C{:}

ans =
   0.9864    0.8223    0.1952    0.0121    0.0012

ans =
   0.1962

an s =
   0.9864    0.2448    0.0014

ans =
    0.9864    0.2448    0.0014
    0.9863    0.2448    0.0014
```

I want to print this on a text file in the same format as we see above without 'ans'; I use fprintf and I get all the output in a single row.

```
[nrows ncols]=size(C);
fid = fopen(saveDataName, 'w');
for row=1:nrows
fprintf(fid, '%12.4f', C{row,:});
fclose(fid);
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

The printf family doesn't implicitly add a newline, so you need to end your format string with "\n". If you want a newline every so many data points, as in your example, just inject fprintf(fid,"\n") as necessary in the loop.

Comment: Hi,SilverbackNet.Thanks for your help. I have already tried that before,but then I get all the output in a single column. I would like my output as we seen in my example. First row with 5 columns,second with 1 column and so on. Note that my cell varies its size and contents everytime. So I need a general code to write a cell into a text file in the same format as MATLAB print it on the command window when we type C{:} but without the word 'ans'. I hope you understand my problem.